# Text Transition Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been looking at this site:
http://foulomatic.hnldesign.nl/

I have been trying to work out how the text animation is generated, but can't see it.

I can see that the relevant CSS is in this file:
http://foulomatic.hnldesign.nl/css/foulomatic.css

e.g.

```
.csstransitions #generated span.blur {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 0.04s ease-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 0.04s ease-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: bounce 0.04s ease-out infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 0.04s ease-out infinite;
    animation: bounce 0.04s ease-out infinite;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    from    {   top: -5px;  opacity: 0.2; }
    50%     {   opacity: 0.5; }
    to      {   top: 5px;   opacity: 0.2; }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    from    {   top: -5px;  opacity: 0.2; }
    50%     {   opacity: 0.5; }
    to      {   top: 5px;   opacity: 0.2; }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce {
    from    {   top: -5px;  opacity: 0.2; }
    50%     {   opacity: 0.5; }
    to      {   top: 5px;   opacity: 0.2; }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
    from    {   top: -5px;  opacity: 0.2; }
    50%     {   opacity: 0.5; }
    to      {   top: 5px;   opacity: 0.2; }
}
```

If I right-click the generated text and inspect the element in Firefox, it appears as e.g.

```
<div class="well result" id="generated">
    <span> food trough</span>
    <span> extractor</span>
</div>
```

However, if I save a local page and run it, including the jQuery and CSS files, the animation doesn't fire.

Can anyone please help explain how this effect is generated?

Hopefully I won't get blasted for asking, as the person who wrote the page has licensed it via http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.5/

Comment: `.csstransitions #generated span.blur` & `<span> food trough</span>` does not match. class is missing on span

Comment: it should be like this (#generated  {) -- demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/5t1asug0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using two javascript files to inject the content into the page, [A "database file"](http://foulomatic.hnldesign.nl/js/generator/_source/db.js?0.9&_=1409168506573) of sorts to hold all of the words in arrays and a [generator file](http://foulomatic.hnldesign.nl/js/generator/core.min.js) to do the randomization / generation. These seem to be the main files associated with creating the page content, so  you can try to save those and plug them into your code; however this has not been tested by me.